# PyInstaller output artifacts in different folders

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pyinstaller

I need to build both executables x32 and x64 and using following commands for it:

```
echo ******************** Starting buiding x32...  ******************
c:\Anaconda32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe src/app.spec
echo ******************** Application was built ******************

echo ******************** Starting buiding x64...  ******************
pyinstaller src/app.spec
echo ******************** Application was built ******************
```

however binaries of above commands saving to the same directories:

> - build
> - dist

Do there any chance to configure different outputs of the PyInstaller? As example:

> - build
>
>   - win32
>   - win64
> - dist
>
>   - win32
>   - win64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution :)

```
echo ******************** Starting buiding x32...  ******************
c:\Anaconda32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --distpath=./dist/win32 --workpath=./build/win32 src/app.spec
echo ******************** Application was built ******************

echo ******************** Starting buiding x64...  ******************
pyinstaller --distpath=./dist/win64 --workpath=./build/win64 src/app.spec
echo ******************** Application was built ******************
```